# It is possible to disable Play Install Referrer API?

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions, android-9.0-pie

As you can see Google introduced this functionality: https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/igetinstallreferrerservice

After updating my app to compile with SDK Api Level 28, now, when installing the update of my app on old devices, it says that the new version of the app has a new permission called "Play Install Referrer API". This will reduce the amount of automatic updates of my application, because automatic updates are only possible if no new permissions are added.

That permission is not in the manifest, so must be something of Api 28.

Also I didn't add any `Play Install Referrer API` source code in my application, just compiled with api 28 and last sdk versions.

Can that be disabled?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: Same issue here, if you found any solution please share it with us